# Symfony3: unable to send form after adding new data dynamically

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

So I was using symfony for a while but there is problem that, each time I face it, I get very angry, seriously :).
Let's assume I have an entity `Client` with `OneToMany` relation with entity `Address`, and let's say I have a form with two selects: Clients and Addresses, so I select a client and load it's addresses in the select below dynamically using ajax, as described in the picture below:
[image]
After sending the form with selected client and address symfony gives me this error about the **addresses select**:
`This value is not valid`
This is my builder that gave me this error:

```
$builder
->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Client::class,

      ))
->add('addresses', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Address::class,
                'choices' => array(), //---To force symfony to not launch a query to get all addresses
      ))
```

When I remove the line `'choices' => array()` the form works fine and send the data correctly.
I really need to solve this issue because I need something like that a lot in my application that I'm now working on it.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, is like you tell Symfony to accept not thing.

```
'choices' => array()
```

Apparently in your app the choice of address depends on each client. So the solution is to use Form Events to Dynamically Modify your forms. Here a good example from the Symfony official document.
[Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)